# Is it possible to restore an Azure Active Directory user using the azure-cli?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I recently deleted a user from Azure Active Directory and am looking to undo this action using Azure CLI. Before reaching out here, I tried looking up documentation and relevant commands but haven't found a clear solution yet.

Comment: Cloud only or hybrid AD?

Comment: In the cloud. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To list the deleted users**, make use of below command:

```bash
az rest --method GET --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user"
```

[image]

> **Note** that: Deleted users will be available up to 30 days to restore. After 30 days the user will be permanently deleted and you will not be able to restore.

**To restore the user from Azure CLI**, make use of below command:

```bash
az rest --method POST --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/ObjectID/restore"
```

[image]

The user is restored successfully:

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can also make use of Azure PowerShell:

**To list the deleted users**, make use of below commands

```
Connect-MSOLService

Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers
Restore-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <string> -AutoReconcileProxyConflicts -NewUserPrincipalName <string>
```

[image]